# combo box is getting vanished when an alert is coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

In my jsp page i have one text box and two combo box. An alert is coming in my jsp page when i am writing something in the textbox. Alert is coming as "username already exists" and after alert that textbox is autorefreshed **but two combo boxes are getting vanished why**? i could not find out what may be the reason any help please? I included the following in head section. Full source for alert is [here](http://csscody.com/demo/jquery-demo/custom-alert-boxes-using-jquery/80/).

http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/alertbox.js

http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/style.css

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/alertbox.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="js/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
        textboxname: this.value
    },function(data){
      if(data.isTrue){
          $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box
          csscody.alert("username already exists");// here alert is coming
                 }
      else{
      }
     });
});
});
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textboxname" style="position: absolute; width: 250px; left: 110px; top: 40px;" />
<br/><br/>

// The following two combo boxes are getting vanished after alert why
<select id="" name="" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 40px; width: 250px;">
     <option value=""></option>
      <option value="somedata">somedata</option>
          </select>
<br/><br/> 
<select id="" >
    <option value="_"></option>
     <option value="somedata">somedata</option>
        </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

check.jsp

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(); 
jsonObj.put("isTrue","true");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```

Comment: I have given check.jsp also please any suggestion why combo boxes are getting vanished after that "username already exists" alert?

Comment: strange dude combo box is disappeared!!

Comment: ya but what may be the reason? please suggest a possible solution

Comment: i have asked about your question to others but i do not know answer about your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its all ok with your code. When i started debug you code i saw some interesting thing in alertbox.js: (line 141 and 178)

```
  if (!$.support.maxHeight) { //IE6
              $('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility' : 'hidden' });
  }
```

This code detect ie6(if read a comment) but seems its buggy.

**Just comment these lines and your problem will be solved.**

And don't forgot to post this bug!
Good luck. And start use debugger :)

Comment: it is always better show the content after close the alert rather changing the code.http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349626/880434

Comment: @user1217615 No problem just ask

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal totally agree with you but there are two problems. 1. When overlay div shown all selects hide its not good. 2. Better post that bug for alertbox.js developer and then get update

Comment: agreed! better to report them and get fixed it. rather changing their code. until they fix recommended to call it in a better way( since there is a workaround).

Answer (score 1):

following code will solve your problem,

```
csscody.alert("username already exists",{ onComplete: function(){
           $('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility' : 'visible' });
      }
 });
```